# Select a MySQL record that hasn't been used before or past a certain date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select 3 random records from a MySQL db where the lastUsedDate (the date the record was last updated) is beyond a set time period or NULL.

My logic is this:

1. If the lastUsedDate is NULL, then this record could be selected.
2. If the lastUsedDate is 7 days or more older than the current date,
   it is a candidate to be randomly selected.
3. I want to ignore dates that are 7 days and younger.

I know **Rand()** is slow, but this table only has 30 records.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE lastUsedDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 7 DAY) OR lastUsedDate IS NULL 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

Eventually, after 30 days, the lastUsedDate will no longer be NULL as all 30 will be used up. This is why I want to recycle rows after 7 days.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: your `>=` is going in the wrong direction ... use `<=`

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: so...what's wrong? Are you not getting your expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE IFNULL(lastUsedDate, '0000-00-00') <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

Since you tagged this as PHP I'm guessing you are running this query inside PHP, in which case why not simplify the query and do more in php

```
$date_limit = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days", time()));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE IFNULL(lastUsedDate, '0000-00-00') <= '$date_limit' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";
```

good luck

Comment: I used your SQL and it worked perfectly. Why did yours work and mine didn't? Aren't we saying the same thing generally?